# What does KubeProxyIncorrectIPVersion mean?

Tags: kubernetes, k3s

I keep seeing the following in `kubectl get events`:

```
7m53s       Warning   KubeProxyIncorrectIPVersion   service/kubernetes             fd93:5638:de0e::b90 in endpoints has incorrect IP version
7m52s       Warning   KubeProxyIncorrectIPVersion   service/kubernetes             fd93:5638:de0e::b90 in endpoints has incorrect IP version
7m48s       Warning   KubeProxyIncorrectIPVersion   service/kubernetes             fd93:5638:de0e::b90 in endpoints has incorrect IP version
7m47s       Warning   KubeProxyIncorrectIPVersion   service/kubernetes             fd93:5638:de0e::b90 in endpoints has incorrect IP version
7m40s       Warning   KubeProxyIncorrectIPVersion   service/kubernetes             fd93:5638:de0e::b90 in endpoints has incorrect IP version
```

The `fd93:5638:de0e:` prefix is assigned by my router; `fd93:5638:de0e::b90` refers to the single master node.

I installed k3s using `curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | sh -` defaults.

**What does this warning mean? Do I need to worry about it? How do I fix it?**

Comment: Hi, it looks like You have `ipv6` addressed endpoint in Your cluster. Do You have `ipv6` intentionally configured in Your cluster?

Comment: Not intentionally, no; I installed k3s with `curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | sh -`, etc., using the defaults. The `fd93:5638:de0e:` prefix appears to be assigned by my router.

Comment: If you are not experiencing any errors it should be fine. However there is an github [issue](https://github.com/rancher/k3s/issues/811) where there are connection errors caused by ipv6 being overwritten over ipv4 endpoints. This can be avoided by setting router not to assign ipv6 addresses dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is because you have IPv6 addresses assigned to services in your cluster. The rest of your cluster is likely using IPv4 so this causes an issue.

Either disable IPv6 on your router or make sure it does not assign IPs dynamically to the cluster.